# I have no ideas whether it's an appositive case or relative-pronoun case

Tags: relative-pronouns, appositives

> I went the distance she went.

Is this sentence kind of an appositive case? 
Can we think of "that" as omitted in the sentence as in "I went the distance (that) she went?
Here, "that" is leading a clause as well as referring to "the distance". 
Like this, if "she went" is used appositively, can we grammatically omit "that"?
This case seems to have something to do with this case in which "the way (that)" is used because we normally don't include "that" when we use "the way (that)" as in "I like the way (that) you're.

But there seem to be also some people who argue that this "that" is just a relative pronoun. But as for the verb "go", I wouldn't agree with them in that generally most native speakers tend not to regard "went" as used transitively in my sentence and if "the distance" is really the object of "went", this sentence (I went the distance, which she went) must sound correct to all native speakers, but as far as I ask them about it, just only few of them would think of the sentence as grammatically correct.

To sum up,

1. Is my sentence an appositive case?
2. If 1 is right, is it grammatically acceptable to omit "that" in the sentence?
3. If 2 is right, can you answer on when to able to grammatically omit "that" or not?
4. Does that sentence have something to do with "the way (that)" usage?

Comment: It's just a relative clause with *that* omitted. The problem with *I went the distance, which she went* is first of all that since it's a restrictive relative, you can't have a comma, and secondly that it is very unnatural because there are far far simpler ways to say the same thing - *I went the same distance as her*; *we both went the same distance*; *I went the same distance that she went*. Also, I'd say that *which* is rarely used in spoken/informal restrictive relatives. I think what is happening is that you are asking native speakers for a judgment of grammaticality, but...

Comment: ... what you are getting from most of them is a judgment of naturalness.

Comment: @Minty but even dictionaries give different definitions on this usage of "go". Oxford defines "go" as an intransitive verb, but Merriam-webster defines "go" as a transitive verb. So, if it's a relative clause, the sentence collides with the definition by Oxford Dictionary.

Comment: The relative clause *[that] she went* relates to *the distance*, but you are talking about the syntactitc relationship between *went* and *the distance*. I don't think there is any incompatibility.

Comment: Although "go" is normally intransitive, in this case, "went the distance" is idiomatic. And yes, "she went" is a relative clause and "that" is omissible. *"the way you're" is ungrammatical; it should be "the way you are".